# Why the react native documentation says that the FlatList component shows a scrolling list?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning to **react native** and I found the following term on [this documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-scrollview).

> If you have a long list of more items that can fit on the screen, you should use a FlatList instead.

Which means that the FlatList component is used for a flat list that is fit on the screen and not scrollable. But on the FlatList [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-listview) it says:

> The FlatList component displays a **scrolling** list of changing, but similarly structured, data.

Please, can anyone tell what does it mean? Because both documentations are going opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lapse in your understanding of the sentence from the first documentation link. It actually says:

> If you have a long list of more items **than** can fit on the screen, you should use a `FlatList` instead.

Notice that it says **than** instead of **that** which are totally opposite of each other. The phrase *than can fit on the screen* means that you have items that *cannot* fit within the current display size, so using `FlatList` is recommended.

Both `ScrollView` and `FlatList` are scrollable components. Some differences are:

- `ScrollView` is a lot more generic. You can nest any sort of component within a `ScrollView` and they won't complain. `FlatList` on the other hand accepts similarly-structured data.
- Components contained within a `ScrollView` will render together when it loads. `FlatList` will only render its children which are within the scope of the screen, and render the remaining ones when user scrolls to them.

**UPDATE:**

*When I say 'display', I mean the phone's actual, physical display, and by 'container' I mean the set of components/items which make up your app's current page, like a combination of text inputs, buttons, views, etc.*

Consider the following Log In form ([source](https://bootdey.com/react-native-snippet/9/Login-form-ui-example)):

[image: Simple login form]

Every item (component) in this container screen is visible on the phone's display since there aren't a lot of components to begin with. You can get away without using the support for scroll here.

However there a lot of times when you have a lot of components in your container but the display can only fit a limited number of them at a time. Rest of the components would, sort of, *spill out* of the phone's display. In those cases, you must use a scrollable component to properly display all of them, and so that your app's user can actually *reach* the components which are out of display's current range. For example an inbox with many messages, or a to-do list with many items:

[image: Android inbox example]

In the image above, phone's display can only show first 6 items in the inbox. What about the rest of them? Of course you have to *scroll* to see them! You may use `ScrollView` or a `FlatList` to enable the support for scrolling here.

Now, if you use `ScrollView` in these cases, *all* children (inbox items) within the container will load when this particular app page loads, i.e. at the same time. Consider an inbox with 3000 items. It would take forever to load all of them at the same time! The user would be waiting for a long time for them to load. Therefore, a simple `ScrollView` won't work here.

Fortunately, we have `FlatList` for that.

When you use `FlatList` to display scrollable components, only a limited number of items will render at a time which can fit the current display (say, 6 items in the example above). What about the remaining 2994 items? `FlatList` will render them dynamically as the user keeps scrolling down.

Comment: Can you please explain this **means that you have items that cannot fit within the current screen size**, what kind of items cannot be fit inside the screen, what situations can be there where this happens? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @DaddyBoy I have updated my answer to add more explanation.